# PredictionIO unnable to get engine running on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, predictionio

Im trying to deploy my classification engine following the [tutorial](https://docs.prediction.io/templates/classification/quickstart/) on AWS.

In localhost, you deploy Event Server in port 7070 and then an engine in port 8000, but in AWS you have Event Server running, and "pio deploy" tries to deploy the engine in 0.0.0.0:8000, or if I try to make an inquiry to my DNS:7070 I get:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "attr0":2, "attr1":0, "attr2":0 }' http://MYDNS:8000/queries.json
curl: (7) Failed to connect to MYDNS port 8000: Connection refused
```

How is the way to get a correct deployment of the engines and make an inquiry using AWS ?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: I get It having a ssh connection using the shell to have the engine deployment, and accesing to my EC2IPpublic:8000 in AWS from another terminal. Still looking for how to get a persistent deployment when I close the ssh connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your question is answered on google groups: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/predictionio-user/13dveknEVJw

Comment: Yes, that's me on google groups :) I forgot to post here the answer! Thank you !